# frequent c2dm message request

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I had develop an android app that allow user to request info from their phone based on chrometophone example.
Everything is working well but i noticed that c2dm message only sent once to the device and subsequence c2dm will only reach phone after screen unlock.

This make me annoy as my app required to get data from phone without unlock screen multiple times. 
Anyone can help on this?

Thanks and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1):

thanks lonel for reply.

I think I found the answer. there is a parameter called "delay_while_idle", chrometophone set this param to true so C2DM will send only when phone not in IDLE.

Comment: Can you help me, how to implement it. A tutorial or code can be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to send messages to the phone while it is in an idle state.Sadly, you can't do it because C2DM messages are only received when the phone is not idle (i.e. unlocked).

On top of that the devices stop the wifi while they have the screen locked and they only bring it up from time to time.